# JAXB conflicting with dataBinding on IDEA + Android plugin

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, jaxb

**Error**

> org.gradle.execution.MultipleBuildFailures: Build completed with 1 failures.
>      Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

I'm getting this this error when I enable dataBinding and try to build on IntelliJ IDEA, building with `gradlew build` works, and on Android Studio works too.

**Versions**

Gradle version: 5.1.1

IDEA: 2019.1.3

Android plugin: (latest as of 18 jun)

Java: 8

---

To reproduce, create a project on Android Studio, enable dataBinding, and open it on IDEA and try to build.

Does anyone know why these conflicts are happening?

Comment: What JDK do you use to run IDE under? If 11, try switching to the 1.8 JDK: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/switching-boot-jdk.html#d746506e20 Also set 1.8 As **Gradle JVM** in Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle settings.

Comment: Try also `--add-modules java.xml.bind` into Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | **Gradle VM options**.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

Right-click on a project module -> Open Module Settings -> Platform Settings | SDKs -> Click on each Android Api in the SDKs list. And make sure Java SDK 1.8 is selected

Answer (score 4):

Android Studio 3.6.3
On Windows,

Go to **File** -> **Project Structure** (Shortcut: Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S)

Navigate to **SDK Location**

From the **JDK location** dropdown, choose **Embedded JDK**

[image]

**P.S.** Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43574427/5465447) to know the possible reasons. So it is the safest option to use the embedded JDK.

Answer (score 1):

For **Artic Fox** Android studio version :

File > ProjectStructure >
There is option "**JDK location was moved to Gradle Settings.**"

[image]

Click on **Gradle Setings**

there is dropdown option as **Gradle JDK**, Select your appropriate jdk version from dropdown
[image]

After this Sync your project and create build.

Answer (score 0):

From @Andrey's comment:

> `--add-modules "java.xml.bind"` into Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Gradle VM options.

Edit: This worked at first, but the same error happened after creating a databinding layout.

Comment: Where is gradle VM options?

Comment: I can't find it either now, but using `org.gradle.jvmargs=--add-modules java.xml.bind` in gradle.properties should have the same effect. This option didn't end up solving the problem though.